# Playwright scrapy infinite scroll isn't working

Tags: python, web-scraping, scroll, scrapy, playwright

I have the following code. It opens up the headless browser and I also see the page getting scrolled but the response object in parse method doesn't have any HTML. When I don't use auto-scrolling this spider works perfectly.

The code is supposed only to extract the product name and product price from this website.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def should_abort_request(req):
   if req.resource_type == "image":
     return True
   if req.method.lower() == 'post':
     return True

return False


scrolling_script = """
  const scrolls = 8
  let scrollCount = 0

  // scroll down and then wait for 5s
  const scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
    scrollCount++

    if (scrollCount === numScrolls) {
      clearInterval(scrollInterval)
    }
  }, 5000)
  """


class AuchanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'auchan'
  custom_settings = {
    'PLAYWRIGHT_ABORT_REQUEST': should_abort_request
  }
  start_urls = ['https://zakupy.auchan.pl/shop/list/8029?shType=id']

  def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_include_page": True,
                "playwright_page_methods": [
                    PageMethod("evaluate", scrolling_script),
                    #PageMethod("wait_for_timeout", 30000),
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "._1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_"),
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "._1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_:nth-child(60)")
                ],
            },
            errback=self.close_page,
            cb_kwargs=dict(main_url=url, page_number=0),
        )

async def parse(self, response, main_url, page_number):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    product_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='_1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_')
    for product_container in product_containers:
        price = product_container.find(class_='_1-UB _1Evs').get_text()
        price = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", price)
        yield {
            'productName': product_container.find(class_='_1DGZ').get_text(),
            'price': price
        }

async def close_page(self, failure):
    page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
    await page.close()
```

Comment: I've updated the post with code

Comment: I've updated the question and the code. Now the code is executable. It also produces correct output if run without autoscroll.

Comment: Thanks. If it works perfect/produces correct output, then you're good, though, right?

Comment: haha, I wish. What I mean is the code is executable.
If you exclude auto-scrolling it will work.
But with auto-scrolling it doesn't.
The headless browser opens up and I also see page getting scrolled. But not able to get anything in response object of parse

Comment: Can you clarify the actual/expected output, and maybe remove the "works perfect"  and "produces the correct output" text?

Comment: the expected output should be scraping all objects of the "scrolled" page.

works perfect/produces correct output = happens if I omit PageMethod("evaluate", scrolling_script), But this only scrapes first page no scrolling

Comment: I think the problem is with "wait_for_selector". I'm not really sure what the problem is maybe I'm not using "wait_for_selector" the right way.

Comment: It's a little weird to use BeautifulSoup along with Playwright. Playwright already works on the live page, so dumping it into a separate HTML parser doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Same thing with `._1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_:nth-child(60)` -- this is a hyper-rigid, brittle selector that's prone to fail.

Comment: thanks, apart from that. what is causing wait_for_selector to fail? given that we have ._1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_ div present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this problem a bit more directly than you're doing. There's no need for BeautifulSoup because Playwright can already select elements on the live page. I'm not sure whether Scrapy is necessary, either, but you can adapt the following Playwright code to Scrapy if you want:

```py
import re
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.37.0
from time import sleep


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    url = "https://zakupy.auchan.pl/shop/list/8029?shType=id"
    page.goto(url)
    page.click("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    page.click("._3YI0")
    text = page.locator("._3MDH").text_content().strip()
    expected = int(re.search(r"\d+$", text).group())
    records = {}

    while len(records) < expected:
        page.keyboard.press("PageDown")
        sleep(0.2)  # save a bit of CPU
        items = page.eval_on_selector_all(
            "._1DGZ",
            """els => els.map(e => ({
              href: e.href,
              text: e.textContent,
            }))""",
        )

        for x in items:
            # assume hrefs are unique
            records[x["href"]] = x

    print(records)
    browser.close()
```

This code dismisses the cookie and ad banners, then presses PageDown until there are no more records to fetch. I'm only pulling out the title and link from the DOM, but you can add more information if you want.

Note that I'm using simpler selectors. The more assumptions in the selector, the more likely it'll fail if any don't hold true. In your case, although the issue was using spaces instead of `.` to identify multiple classes on one element (spaces denote ancestors), not using so many classes in the first place would have avoided confusion. Sanity check your selectors in the browser console first, keeping in mind this doesn't guarantee they'll work in Playwright, given the different environment. The browser can generate sample selectors. Although these are usually overly-specific, they're at least valid and can be refined to be more reliable.

Also, I realize it's probably better to use the text on the bottom of the page "Załadowano 361 produkt(y) na 361" to determine when all records have been scraped, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

---

Another approach is to intercept requests rather than scrape the document, which provides a lot more data (~2 MB for the page provided):

```py
import json
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from time import sleep


def scrape(page):
    url = "https://zakupy.auchan.pl/shop/list/8029?shType=id"
    items = []
    done = False

    def handle_response(response):
        nonlocal done
        api_url = "https://zakupy.auchan.pl/api/v2/cache/products"

        if response.url.startswith(api_url):
            data = response.json()
            items.append(data)

            if data["pageCount"] == data["currentPage"]:
                with open("out.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(items, f)
                    done = True

    page.on("response", handle_response)
    page.goto(url)
    page.click("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    page.click("._3YI0")

    while not done:
        page.keyboard.press("PageDown")
        sleep(0.2)  # save a bit of CPU


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    scrape(browser.new_page())
    browser.close()
```

You can then loop over the JSON with [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to extract whatever information you want, say, the names:

```
jq '.[].results | .[] | .defaultVariant.name' < out.json
```

or in Python:

```py
for x in items:
    for x in x["results"]:
        print(x["defaultVariant"]["name"])
```

with a list comp:

```py
[x["defaultVariant"]["name"] for y in items for x in y["results"]]
```

Note that the above version misses the first page of records, which can be grabbed from the DOM or with a separate request that uses headers copied from another API request.

However, once you go into request interception territory, you can hijack a request to their API and wire it to return 500 items, collecting all of the data more quickly and easily:

```py
import json
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from time import sleep


def scrape(page):
    url = "https://zakupy.auchan.pl/shop/list/8029?shType=id"
    api_url = "https://zakupy.auchan.pl/api/v2/cache/products"
    new_url = "https://zakupy.auchan.pl/api/v2/cache/products?listId=8029&itemsPerPage=500&page=1&cacheSegmentationCode=019_DEF&hl=pl"
    done = False

    def handle(route, request):
        route.continue_(url=new_url)

    page.route("https://zakupy.auchan.pl/api/v2/cache/products*", handle)

    def handle_response(response):
        nonlocal done

        if response.url.startswith(api_url):
            with open("out1.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(response.json(), f)
                done = True

    page.on("response", handle_response)
    page.goto(url)
    page.click("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    page.click("._3YI0")

    while not done:
        page.keyboard.press("PageDown")
        sleep(0.2)  # save a bit of CPU


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    scrape(browser.new_page())
    browser.close()
```

This structure can be processed as follows, using the example of grabbing names:

```
jq '.results | .[] | .defaultVariant.name' < out1.json
```

or in Python:

```py
for x in data["results"]:
    print(x["defaultVariant"]["name"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it ignores the data on the first page and only starts scraping from page 2 onwards.

Comment: Which code block are you referring to? The last block pulls down everything from the API as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think it is ignoring the first page because it closes the cookies and Christmas ad. Even when you look at out.json you'll see at the top "currentPage": 2,

Comment: just saw your edited post. Works for all pages. Awesome. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was in `wait_for_selector`. The div should not have 'spaces' in there. Instead, the spaces should be replaced with '.'. This is how `wait_for_selector` should look like. `PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "._1E5b._2I59._1wkJ._3YFw.igxN._7Zx6.Eb4X._390_"),`