# scrapy playwright doesn't extract all div child elements

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

My following scrapy playwright code is unable to extract all the div child nodes. The max depth it goes to is 1 child. So the div I'm providing plus the direct child below it. When I print this is how the div looks like

`<div class="_1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_"><div class="_2UOo _3pKQ" style="min-width: 198px; min-height: 432px;"><!-- --></div></div>`

whereas the `_1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_` has over 15 child nodes underneath. Here's my code:

```
name = 'auchan'
    custom_settings = {
        'PLAYWRIGHT_ABORT_REQUEST': should_abort_request
    }
    start_urls = ['https://zakupy.auchan.pl/shop/list/8029?shType=id']

def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse,
                # dont_filter=True,
                meta={
                    "playwright": True,
                    "playwright_page_methods": [
                         PageMethod("evaluate", scrolling_script),
                         #PageMethod("wait_for_timeout", 30000),
                         PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div._1E5b._2I59._1wkJ._3YFw.igxN._7Zx6.Eb4X._390_"),
                         PageMethod("wait_for_selector",
                                    "div._1E5b._2I59._1wkJ._3YFw.igxN._7Zx6.Eb4X._390_:nth-child(60)")
                    ],
                    "playwright_include_page": True,
                },
                errback=self.close_page,
                cb_kwargs=dict(main_url=url, page_number=0),
            )

async def parse(self, response, main_url, page_number):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        product_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='_1E5b _2I59 _1wkJ _3YFw igxN _7Zx6 Eb4X _390_')
        for product_container in product_containers:
            price = product_container.find(class_='_1-UB _1Evs').get_text()
            price = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", price)
            yield {
                'productName': product_container.find(class_='_1DGZ').get_text(),
                'price': price
            }
```

Comment: this is a different question. I figured the previous one.

Comment: respect your comments. Restored the question and also self-answered it. Please shed some light on this one.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. If you take a look at [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77668230/6243352), I show how to pull 2 megabytes of data down, which probably contains all of the data you want for this question as well. Can you show the exact output you want? I'm pretty sure it's a short step from having all the data to walking the JSON and extracting what you need, all without DOM traversal or selectors.